# Подскажите как исправить ошибку Е0065 в коде?

Tags: c++, консоль

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int age = 25; 
    int *pAga = &age;

    cout << "Age equals " << age << endl;
    cout << "Address is variable age: 0x " << pAga << endl;

    cout << "Enter an age:";
    cin >> *pAga;

    cout << "How age equals " << age << endl;
    cout << "How value has 0x " << pAga "address" << endl;// Ошибка Е0065

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, просто написать

```
cout << "How value has 0x " << pAga << " address" << endl;
```